# Convert Base64 string to BitmapImage C# Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, base64, jpeg, bitmapimage

I receive a image/jpeg;base64 string from server.
How can I convert this string to BitmapImage and set like Image.Source ?

```
string imgStr = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAAQABAAD .... ";
BitmapImage bmp = Base64StringToBitmap(imgStr);
myImage.Source = bmp;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can get the bytes with `byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);` but do not know how to set in your image control.

Comment: Vitor Canova, thanks! I can usebyteBuffer with memoryStream and set it like Source for BitmapImage!

Comment: Maybe post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find solution for my issue:

```
public static BitmapImage Base64StringToBitmap(string  base64String)
{
    byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream);

    memoryStream.Close();
    memoryStream = null;
    byteBuffer = null;

    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if things changed in .Net 6 or what but for me this solution did not work. After various tests I was able to get it working by: 1. not closing the memoryStream, so removed the line `memoryStream.Close();`, and 2. calling the `BitmapImage.BeginInit()` before the line `bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream);`, similarly 3. calling the `BitmapImage.EndInit()` after the line `bitmapImage.SetSource(memoryStream);`. I've confirmed all three are required to work in my case.