# How to convert base64 string to BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, base64, bitmapimage

I'm reading data from a blob in MySQL in Base64 String.
I want to convert this to a BitmapImage.
I've tried many ways, but without success.
Here is an example:

```
    public static BitmapImage Base64ToBitmapImage(this string base64String)
    {
        byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        img.BeginInit();
        img.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(binaryData);
        img.EndInit();
        return img;
    }
```

One example of blob:

```
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
```

Comment: "but without success" doesn't tell us anything about what happens with the code you've already got, other than that it doesn't work. Does it throw an exception? Just not show anything?

Comment: Related: [Convert Base64 string to BitmapImage C# Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624865/convert-base64-string-to-bitmapimage-c-sharp-windows-phone)

Comment: No suitable imaging components were found to complete this operation.

Comment: If you have additional details like error messages etc., please edit the question to add these details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above works fine. The cause of the problem its on MySQL return.
The value from a blob column returns returns as a byte on C# MySQL Lybrary.
And I was converting it to a Base64 String and recoverting to a byte.

I excluded this confusion in my code and problem fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In my project, I used this method to convert an array of bytes to BitmapImage:

```cs
public static BitmapImage? ConvertToBitmapImage(byte[]? imageData)
        {
            if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
            {
                mem.Position = 0;
                image.BeginInit();
                image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.UriSource = null;
                image.StreamSource = mem;
                image.EndInit();
            }
            image.Freeze();
            return image;
        }
```

You can use this function by passing an array of bytes to it:

```cs
public static BitmapImage? Base64ToBitmapImage(this string base64String)
    {
        byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        return ConvertToBitmapImage(binaryData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this functions.

```
private string ImageToBase64String(string file)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        byte[] arr = new byte[ms.Length];

        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(arr, 0, (int)ms.Length);
        ms.Close();

        string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(arr);

        return strBase64;
    }

   
    private Bitmap Base64StringToImage(string base64)
    {
        byte[] arr = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arr);
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);

        return bitmap;
    }
```